# Spring Boot with Security is not serving my static content

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-security

Hi Here is My Security Config File and i'm using Spring Boot 2.0.6.RELEASE
and my static content files are in static folder only static->css, js, images, fonts

i have tried all the other posts solution but none of them worked for me and still static contents are secured styles are not getting applied etc. thanks in advance

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
public class SecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

    private final String[] PUBLIC_MATCHER = {"/css/**","/js/**","/fonts/**","/images/**", "/"};

    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {

        http
            .authorizeRequests()
            .antMatchers(PUBLIC_MATCHER)
            .permitAll().anyRequest().authenticated()
            .and()
            .csrf().disable().cors().disable()
            .formLogin().failureUrl("/login?error").defaultSuccessUrl("/dashboard")
            .loginPage("/login").permitAll()
            .and()
            .logout().logoutRequestMatcher(new AntPathRequestMatcher("/logout"))
            .logoutSuccessUrl("/?logout").deleteCookies("remember-me").permitAll()
            .and()
            .rememberMe();

       }
    }
 }
```

Comment: If you disable Spring Security can you access that static content?

Comment: Well i tried it out locally, and my answer wasn't right (i deleted it). It works fine for me, so maybe you are trying to get the resources on a wrong URL, or the resources are not exist

Answer (score 0):

Add this method in your security Config file,hope it will work

```
//this method allows static resources to be neglected by spring security
        @Override
        public void configure(WebSecurity web) throws Exception {
            web
                .ignoring()
                .antMatchers("/resources/**", "/static/**","/css/**","/js/**","/fonts/**","/images/**");
        }
```